# Python - Join two arrays in to one list

Tags: python

I´m new to python and don´t know what to search for in forums i just know the specific problem i have, so when i searching around i don´t find what im lokking for... so please how do i join two arrays into one list or tuple?

```
file = [] # a,b,c,d,e,f,..
date = [] # 1,2,3,4,5,6,...
array_list = [a,1],[b,2],[c,3],....
```

Is it even possible to do that?

Comment: Try `list(zip(file, date))`

Comment: loop through file or date and add file to index  0 and date to index 1

Answer (score 0):

Simply you could merge two lists using the built-in `zip` function in python,

```
list(zip(file, date))
```

Comment: It will give output like [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')] not like [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']] .

Comment: `import numpy as np
 a=np.array([1,2,3])
 b=np.array(['a','b','c'])
 c=zip(a,b)
 print c
`
And You would get output as below:

 `   [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
`
However, you can convert your, tuples in to list too like as below:

 `   new_output = map(lambda x:list(x),c) 
    print new_output
`
And You would get output as below:
       [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']]

Comment: You've made your point, but writing so much code for just converting an immutable item into a mutable one, can be termed unnecessary, where tuples can perform what lists are meant to be.

Comment: Actual code is very small, It seeming you long because i have declared variable, library import (Numpy) and all. However, single line code is 

`map(lambda x:list(x),zip(file,date))
`

Comment: @AakashGoel or rather `map(list,zip(file,date))` but to get a real list in python 3 you have to do `[list(x) for x in zip(file,date)]`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Above code `map(lambda x:list(x),zip(file,date))` is according to python 2.7 Version.

Comment: my point: `lambda x:list(x)` => just `list`